# Unknown pseudo-op: .global

Tags: macos, assembly

I'm trying to compile a simple operating system code we got on OS class. It works fine under Ubuntu but I'd like to compile it on OS X. The error I get is:

```
[compiling] arch/i386/arch/startup.S ...
arch/i386/arch/startup.S:8:Unknown pseudo-op: .extern
arch/i386/arch/startup.S:8:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 107 (k).
arch/i386/arch/startup.S:11:Expected comma after segment-name
arch/i386/arch/startup.S:13:Unknown pseudo-op: .global
arch/i386/arch/startup.S:13:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 97 (a).
```

This is the
[source code of that file](http://pastebin.com/r2MEbp0f), and here is the [makefile](http://pastebin.com/mL4LA9dE)

So if anyone have an idea what to do I would appreciate it :)

Comment: @trojanfoe His makefile says that he's using `gcc`

Comment: @PavanManjunath It doesn't tell me the version though.

Comment: @trojanfoe Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5666.3~123/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)

Answer (score 5):

As you're compiling using OS/X you'll be using X-Code's ancient version of `as`. This means you'll have to put up with some slightly older syntax. This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904597/building-arm-assembler-vorbis-decoder-lib-tremolo-for-iphone) covers some of these problems.

At very least you're going to need to replace `.global` with `.globl`. You can remove `.extern` as all symbols are treated as external by default. For the section definition you should consult the [`gas` manual](http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/scientific4/docs/rhel-as-en-4/section.html); I believe the assembler is asking you to define the section flags.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be ".globl" not ".global"